# ApplyCurrentValues does not seem to work

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I try to do the following with entity framework 4 :

```
public void Update(Site entity)
{
    using (db)
    {
        db.Sites.Attach(db.Sites.Single(s => s.Id == entity.Id));
        db.Sites.ApplyCurrentValues(entity);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But when i try to update a site through this method i get an error telling me that :

> The conversion of a datetime2 data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value. The
>   statement has been terminated.

And this is because the original site for some reason is not loaded through the Attach() method.

Can someone help with this ?

/Martin

Comment: You don't need to attach loaded entity. If you are using same context it is already attached. Are you sure that your current values don't override some loaded value with DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: When I remove the Attach() part I get this error : "An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of the supplied object match the key values of the object to which changes must be applied." So I think the entity is no longer in the ObjectState

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to "attach" something you are already retrieving (Ladislav is right). Once you retrieve an entity (e.g SingleOrDefault), it is "in the graph" (EF memory - so it can do optimistic concurrency).

If your trying to do an UPDATE< and the "entity" your passing through is new/detached...

**Try the stub technique**:

```
public void Update(Site entity)
{
    using (db)
    {
        var stub = new Site { Id = entity.Id }; // create stub with given key
        db.Sites.Attach(stub); // stub is now in graph
        db.Sites.ApplyCurrentValues(entity); // override graph (stub) with entity
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

That being said, the error you have provided points to some other issue (data conversion).

Have you checked the "date" values you are passing through with the data type on the model?

Comment: As mentioned above to Ladislav Mrnka comment I get an error when I try to remove the Attach() method. How ever when I do what you suggest with the stub technique, it works. Does it have to do with that i'm using EF4 within Domain Driven Design?

Comment: @Martin Overgaard - no it doesn't. I also have to use the stub technique, because i use POCO's and ASP.NET MVC (so my entities are detached from the graph at start of new request - stateless - HTTP). It has nothing to do with DDD. It's required for entities that are detached from the context, but you know they are existing and you need to UPDATE them. It's an Alex James technique. Please tick this as the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Client collection)
{
   try
   {
      // make sure the rec is in the context
      var rec = dbEntities.Clients.First(r => r.ClientID == id);  
      // update the rec in the context with the parm values
      dbEntities.Clients.ApplyCurrentValues(collection);          
      // make the changes permanent
      dbEntities.SaveChanges();                                   
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
      return View();
    }
}
```